# How set an Enum value as selectedItem in a combobox in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, enums

Ok so I have found a lot of question about this here but all of them seems old and complicated to me.

I have a combobox what is binded to a viewmodel class.

```
class SettingsViewModel
{
    public PictureRecognitionIntensivity PictureRecognitionIntensivity { get; set; }

    public Array PictureRecognitionIntensivityValues
    {
        get { return PictureRecognitionIntensivity.GetValues(typeof(PictureRecognitionIntensivity)); }
    }

    public SettingsViewModel()
    {
        // Set default values for testing;
        this.PictureRecognitionIntensivity = PictureRecognitionIntensivity.Moderate;
    }


}
```

The XAML part:

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Path=PictureRecognitionIntensivity}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GetPictureRecognitionIntensivityValues}" />
```

This code properly load the values into the combobox and when the selection is changed the value change to the selected item so it works properly except it it doesnt load the initial state into the combobox. (It is empty at the beginnings.)

Somewhere I saw that the Enum.GetValues gives back a strings so I tried to convert it to string like this:

```
return this.PictureRecognitionIntensivity.toString();
```

But it didn't work either. My question what is the simple and easy way to add an enum instance to a combobox and set the selectedItem for it.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way I suggest for a given enum

```
public enum PictureRecognitionIntensivity
{
    FIRST,
    SECOND,
    THIRD,
    FORTH,
}
```

declare the static instance in view resource as below

```
    <Window.Resources>
      <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="dataFromEnum" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type System:Enum}">
         <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="local:PictureRecognitionIntensivity"/>
         </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
      </ObjectDataProvider>
   </Window.Resources>
```

then in your ComboBox bind it as follows:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource dataFromEnum}}" SelectedItem="{Binding intensity }"/>
```

then setting the initial enum value should work as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

The GetValues return an array of integers as enumerations can be casted to numbers, you must convert them to strings, and then change your property to be an string (internally you will store the enum value).

```
    class SettingsViewModel
    {

        PictureRecognitionIntensivity intensity;

        public string Intensivity 
        { 
            get
            {
                return intensity.ToString(); 
            } 

            set
            { 
                intensity = (PictureRecognitionIntensivity)Enum.Parse(typeof(PictureRecognitionIntensivity), value); 
            } 
        }

        public string[] PictureRecognitionIntensivityValues
        {
            get {

                List<string> values = new List<string>();

                Array iValues = PictureRecognitionIntensivity.GetValues(typeof(PictureRecognitionIntensivity));

                foreach(int value in iValues)
                    values.Add(((PictureRecognitionIntensivity)value).ToString());

                return values.ToArray();

            }
        }

        public SettingsViewModel()
        {
            // Set default values for testing;
            this.intensity = PictureRecognitionIntensivity.Moderate;
        }


    }
```

Comment: I copied and binded the properties properly but this doesn't work. The result same as for my solution. The itemSource fill the combobox but the initial value is not set. (I tried to bind it like this `<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Intensivity}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PictureRecognitionIntensivityValues}" />` )

Answer (score 0):

Maybe can help to set the SelectedValue instead of SelectedItem:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource dataFromEnum}}" SelectedValue="{Binding Source={x:Static props:UserSettings.Instance}, Path=DefaultCalcMethod}">
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you have not implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

See this sample code :

Window1.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cmbChessTitles" SelectedItem="{Binding ChosenTitle, Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="25" Width="200" Height="45"></ComboBox>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="246,121,0,0" Text="{Binding ChosenTitle}" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="39" Width="200" Background="#FFF01313"/>
</Grid>
```

Window1.xaml.cs

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
   public ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();

   public Window1()
   {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.DataContext = vm;
    cmbChessTitles.ItemsSource = vm.Titles;

    vm.ChosenTitle = ChessTitles.WorldChampion;
    cmbChessTitles.SelectedItem = vm.ChosenTitle;
   }
}

public class ViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Array Titles
    {
        get { return Enum.GetValues(typeof(ChessTitles)); }
    }

    private ChessTitles _chosenTitle;
    public ChessTitles ChosenTitle
    {
        get{ return _chosenTitle ;}
        set { _chosenTitle = value; OnPropertyChanged("ChosenTitle"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        if(PropertyChanged !=null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}

public enum ChessTitles
{
    WorldChampion,
    GrandMaster,
    FideMaster,
    InternationalMaster
}
```